# What problems have folks encountered sending DataTable / Collection to SQL Server using TVP

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

If any of you are using the new TVP to pass a collection to SQL Server what issues have you encountered with that process? I am thinking about implmenting it, but wanted to get some feedback on potential pitfalls with going with that solution.  I like passing XML for flexibility and the ability to pass collections, but I don't want to have to shred the xml with SQL Server (Doesn't seem like it will scale well).  Anyways just wanted to get some feedback from some of the more experienced users....always really helpful.

Thanks,

S

Comment: Please re-read the [faq], especially [ask].

Comment: @JohnSaunders can you be specific? My question was specific, On point, relevant, etc.  I have done my homework on how to approach the problem, but being new to the subject wanted to get some feedback from some folks that have field tested the approach.  If I in any by passed the stack code policy let me know.  I was trying to be specific about issues others have encountered and didn't think it was subjective at all?

Comment: We don't really like "what's your opinion" questions, as they're open-ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using TVPs for half a year so far, and I did not have any issues at all. I do not send more than 1K rows at a time. Before TVPs were available, I was packing numbers in binary format into an image, and casting parts of an image back into numbers on the server - that scaled very well, performed real fast for up to 100K numbers.

Comment: Thanks Alex I appreciate the info.  Interesting idea to pack into binary.